# How to Convert Hex String to Uint8

Tags: c++, casting

I would like to know why I am getting the result of 0 when converting a hex string (0x1) to a uint8.

I tried to use `boost::lexical_cast` but I get a `bad_lexical_cast` exception. Therefore, I decided to use a `stringstream` instead but I am getting the incorrect value.

```
...
uint8_t temp;
std::string address_extension = "0x1";
std::cout << "Before: " << address_extension << std::endl;
StringToNumeric(address_extension, temp);
std::cout << "After: " << temp << std::endl;
...

template <typename T>
void StringToNumeric(const std::string& source, T& target)
{
    //Check if source is hex
    if(IsHexNotation(source))
    {
       std::stringstream ss;
       //Put value in the stream
       ss << std::hex << source;
       //Stream the hex value into a target type
       ss >> target;
     }

 }
```

You can be assured that `IsHexNotation()` works correctly and does not change the source as it is declared:

```
bool IsHexNotation(const std::string& source)
```

What is the correct way to convert a hex string to a uint8 (given that the hex string WILL fit into the datatype)?

Comment: Hex is a *representation* of a numeric value value, just like decimal or Roman numerals.  You *format* it or *scan* it, you don't *cast* it.

Comment: @HotLicks That makes sense - I had never thought of it that way (and thus why lexical cast did not work - it didn't know what to do with it!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using code like this works for me:

```
std::stringstream ss;
int target(0);
ss << std::hex << source;
if (ss >> target) {
    std::cout << "value=" << target << '\n';
}
else {
    std::cout << "failed to read value\n";
}
```

However, I remember that there was a discussion on where the read position of a string stream should be after a write. Since it mostly follows the model of file streams, you'd need to seek to desired position, even if it is the same position. Some implementations used a common position and others used separate read and write positions. You can try using

```
ss.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
```

to make sure that the read position is at the start of the stream. Alternatively, and in my opinion preferable, is to initialize an `std::istringstream` and read from that directly:

```
std::istringstream in(source);
if (in >> std::hex >> target) { ... }
```

Note, that you always want to check if the extraction was successful: this way you get a hint that something actually went wrong and the value `0` may be just some initial value of the variable.

Comment: After trying your implementation, it seems that my problem is with using `uint8_t`. When I use just `int`, as you have, it works fine. Any ideas on why this would cause a change?

Comment: @larrylampco: You hadn't mentioned your choice of type for `target` and I had assumed it would be a proper integer: although character types generally behave like small integers, they don't always do so. The formatted read functions for characters start off by skipping whitespace (assuming `std::ios_base::skipws` is set which is the default) and then read one character. That is, your `uint8_t` read the value `'0'` (not the value `0` or `'\0'`) rather than attempting to read a hex value.